How to copy paste Kannada text from pdf or word doc to google translate text field?
I have a document written in Kannada both in pdf format and doc format. It is readable. But if I copy paste some text from it to the google translate text field (language set to Kannada manually), it shows garbage like"£Á£ÀÄ ªÉÄÃ®ÌAqÀ «¼Á¸". How can we perform this copy paste successfully?

Are your language settings in Word set to Kannada? If yes, is Kannada applied to the text? If yes, is the text in a font that supports the correct character set?
